# OpenCV242 on eclipse in windows

Tags: c, eclipse, opencv

I want to work with OpenCV2.4.2 . and I tried  a simple progam to test if it'll work  here is the code :

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Nothing but create a window
  cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 100, 100);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

wenn I try to build and run this I get this error message from Eclipse :

```
fatal error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
line 63, external location:      D:\opencv\include\opencv\cv.h C/C++ Problem




Symbol 'CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE' could not be resolved   source.c    line 18 Semantic Error
```

Any Idea why it doesn't work ??

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler does not know the location of opencv headers.